# Issue installing Spring Tools 3 add on for Spring Tools 4.3.9.14.CI

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am trying to install Spring Tools 3 add on for Spring Tools 4.3.9.14.CI using eclipse market place in Spring tool 4.x. It is giving the below error.

> Unable to read repository at https://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.16-sts471r/content.xml.
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: The error message is related to your JDK/JRE not having the certificate installed. If you search on SO for the error message, you will find plenty of answers and solutions for that. If that doesn't help, you could also try to install the STS3 components manually using the "Install New Software" action and use, e.g., the `https://download.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.16-sts471r` URL, sometimes switching the URL helps as well.

Comment: I would also be highly interested to learn about the reasons why you wanna install that extension into Spring Tools 4, since the long-term plan is to NOT maintain the STS3 components anymore sometime soon. So learning about why people still install this and what is maybe missing from the Spring Tools 4 would be super helpful.